# Using RDP bastion host to access Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to set up an AWS VPC with multiple servers in private subnets, a mix of Windows and RHEL

The bastion host is likely to be an RDP server in a separate management VPC linked via VPC peering

Is it bad practice to use the RDP box to SSH into the Linux servers via Putty, providing we don't store the private keys on the RDP bastion and use SSH agent forwarding via Paegent or similar? Or is that a common and acceptable use case?

Answer (score 2):

It makes a lot of sense to have an RDP based bastion host at the front of your network. Simply because there are so few other options (especially in a mixed environment). In fact your choices very much come down to that or a VPN (both is obviously even better)

A bastion host provides an additional layer of security, for a defense in depth security practice. It gives another chance for you to detect and prevent an attack on your network.

RDP is a reasonably well secured protocol, although there are attack vectors into it there are also built in ways to mitigate them once configured correctly.

The first step would be to ensure that you have [Network Level Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Level_Authentication) configured, this will reduce the ability to directly attack the RDP session by requiring authentication prior to initiation. Requiring less resources for rejected sessions making DDOS attacks less successful. NLA can be configured with TLS to provide mutual authentication.

The RDP Protocol itself provides the option for mandatory strong / fips compliant encryption, as well as further certificate authentication.

On top of that you could use IPSEC to provide IP Level security.

Obviously strong complex passwords (or even smartcard login) would be advisable, as is not being in the same domain as the other Windows machines. With regular auditing of the security log to be aware of the attacks that are being presented. (ideally with some automated anomaly reporting)

Finally carefully choose the rules that you apply to the Security Group between the two networks. Consider the implications of an attacker getting access to the bastion, how much authentication do they then need to get further. What is the attack surface they can see from that point. Ideally that should just be more RDP and SSH. Putting management tools on the bastion does hand over the keys to the empire if they manage to break into that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider having private subnet only and include a virtual private gateway that allows you to communicate with your on-premises via an IPsec VPN tunnel. It's much safe than using bastion host because you don't expose your network to the Internet at all.

More information about this configuration here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario4.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, no it isn't bad practice. It's just one of many practices that you can employ.